# Solve quadratic diophantine equation in two variables.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine all $m,n\in \mathbb Z^+$ such that $m^2+1$ is a prime number and $10(m^2+1)=n^2+1$. Please provide complete explanation with solution.

Comment: ...please...? What have you done so far?

Comment: I have put in all the possible combinations in excel sheet and checked which values match both the conditions.   However, I believe there is a proper way of solving this question.   I am looking at Lagrange's Algorithm to solve this question; but I can't understand it completely.

Comment: Well, if $\;m\;$ is odd then $\;m^2+1\;$ is even...This is a very weird question. And read the directions on how to ask in this site.

Comment: I apologize for my question.

Comment: $10m^2=n^2-9$ ought to get you started.

Comment: https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM calculates the solution (there re infinetly many) for $10m^2-n^2+9=0$, ignoring the prime number condition and the condition that the solution should be positive. Use a=10, c=-1, f=9 and the remaining coefficients =0,  There is a "Show steps" button that explains the calculation.

Comment: I don't know if this helps :-)

Comment: Thank you miracle173, for the site.   :-)         however, unfortunately, I am not able to understand the steps; especially from "The algorithm requires that the coefficient of X² and the right hand side are coprime... ... ...   "    :-(

Comment: actually i can't understand from "10 X² - 1 = -14400 ...   "   onwards

Comment: One solution is $m=2$  and $ n=7$ where $2^2+1=5$ is a prime.

Answer (score 0):

Fermat numbers $F=2^2+1=5$ and $F=2^{2^2}+1= 17$ resulted from $k=1$ and $k=2$ in $F_n=2^{2^k}+1$ give $7$ and $13$ for n in equation $10(m^2+1)=n^2+1$ where it results in $m=2$ and $m=4$ respectively. So one set of solutions could be a combination of solutions $(m=± 2..  and.. m= ± 4)$ with $(n=± 17.. and.. n= ± 13)$.

It is not known all Fermat primes give integers for n.It can be checked by brute force.On RHS the last digit of $n^2$ must be 9 so that $10 | n^2+1$ , so the last digit of n can only be 3 or 7.This can also be checked by brute force to see whether there are more solutins.